# RSpec Not Rendering the Head tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, view, rspec

I'm doing some testing against the creation of canonical links on our site, and am running into the following Webrat issue in RSpec.

Here's the test:

```
[...setup stuff...]
it "should not render a canonical link rel" do
  assign(:post, @post)
  render
  rendered.should have_selector('link', { :rel => 'canonical', :href => post_path(@post, :only_path => false)})
end
```

And here's the results:

```
   Failure/Error: rendered.should have_selector('link', { :rel => 'canonical', :href => post_path(@post, :only_path => false)})
   expected following output to contain a <link href='http://test.host/posts/123913-post-name' rel='canonical'/> tag:
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">

   <html><body>

   <div>
   [.... lots more stuff that is rendered properly ....]
```

As you can see, there is no  tag rendered between the html and the body tags. However, when I access the page directly (using our server), no problem. Is this a configuration issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here was in the "render" call. Instead of just saying "render", i need to set the template and the layout. Here's what worked:

```
it "should render a canonical link rel" do
  assign(:post, @post)
  render :template => "posts/show", :layout => "layouts/application"
  rendered.should have_selector('link', { :rel => 'canonical', :href => post_path(@post, :only_path => false)})
end
```